# Cannot find patterns in the input file while importing CSV into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to import some pretty simple data into my SQL Server 2014 from a `csv` file.

In the `csv` file, I only have a single column with numeric data.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 17.6 and I connect to my database, then use Task `Import Flat File` feature.

This is the error I see when I pick the file and click next:
[image]

Any idea what the problem is and how to get around it?

UPDATE:

Not quite the same as providing an actual file but here's a screen shot of the file. It contains phone numbers. I obfuscated the actual numbers so that we don't jeopardize anyone's privacy.

[image]

Comment: You are importing a flat file, is the file truely a flat file?  It should give you an options screen before this for settings in your flat file you are importing, what settings do you have there?  Maybe one of those is incorrect.  You listed Excel in your post tags, but Excel is not flat file.

Comment: Are you able to create and post a small file that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Brad It was an Excel file that I saved as CSV.

Comment: You can import it as Excel still if it is .csv still.  Importing Excel files (from the UI) has less options to select and is usually easier to import. To confirm it is saved as a .csv file right click on the file and click edit with notepad and if it opens good your file is fine, if it opens all messed up it was not saved properly as a .csv file.  I would say just import the original Excel file

Comment: @TabAlleman See update in original post. The file contains phone numbers so I can't post the actual file but providing a screen shot of the obfuscated version of numbers.

Comment: @Brad I resorted to trying `csv` file after my Excel import attempts failed. I figured a standard `csv` is pretty common. Anyway, I now saved the Excel file in Excel 97 format and was able to import it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, one thing when importing an Excel file you have to make sure you select the correct version of Excel from the UI when importing, that may have been your initial issue/error the versions were not correct from your file and the import wizard.

Comment: @Sam, sorry, you've posted a screenshot of your file open in Excel, which isn't enough to reproduce your issue.  Excel could be hiding formatting information and other stuff.   Can you post in plain text, some rows that we could paste into Notepad, save as a .csv, and reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 5):

*edited original post to address the initial issue

I received the same error trying to import a csv file with only one column. [This seems to be a known error with the new import flat file wizard added in SSMS 17.3.](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32898520-import-flat-file-wizard-in-ssms-17-3-cannot-handle) As your data only has one column, it is throwing an error at the preview data step.

The work around is to right click your database, go to tasks => import data. This will start the data import wizard and you will be able to follow [the import steps here to bring your data into a table.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/welcome-to-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017)